# How to find the address of a cell found by LOOKUP and then fetch a corresponding cell?

Tags: excel, vba

So this is a new post, see the screen dump attached, please.

[image: The code has to find the last non-zero value in Col A of this sheet and then fetch the value in Col C in the same row and paste it in C3.]

Code:

```
Sub FindFetch()

' Find the last non-zero value in Col A and then fetch the corresponding value

    ActiveSheet.Range("A3").Formula = "= LOOKUP(2,1/(A10:A26>0),A10:A26)"
     ' Fetch the value in the corresponding column C:
     ' xxx <- this is my problem, how to get there
    ActiveSheet.Range("Cxxx").Copy
    Range("C3").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
        False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 2):

```
= LOOKUP(2,1/(A10:A26>0),C10:C26)
```

Comment: It works very nicely. And it looks so simple! I was expecting something complicated but, as usual, Less is more. Thank you ever so much!

Comment: @JSP Glad to help.  Since this seems to be what you need, I would appreciate it if you could mark my response as the answer (check box in the upper left).

Comment: I cannot see where that checkbox is. I upvoted slightly above this comment so that it shows "2" but I did that a long ago, so I do not really know whether you wrote that *before* I upvoted the answer!?

Comment: @JSP Odd.  I thought that check box would be somewhere below where you upvoted the answer.  It only shows up if you are the person who asked the original question.